# Sudoku in lately updates

Tags: 16.04, updates

I never installed a Sudoku on my computer, but late updates suggest updating a software named *Sudoku*.

Lately I upgraded my 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, is Sudoku software a default on this OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Sudoku comes with 16.04 (and 14.04) by default.